# How do I wire an MVH-150UI to a Peugeot 206?

Tags: ignition, audio, peugeot

Its just flattening my battery and leaving car headlights on? Even used ISO an adapter. Stereo is staying on when I have ignition off.  Can someone tell me how to do this as don't really fancy paying £30 at Halfords to fit the radio!!

Comment: Thanks, its a pioneer mhv-150ui, been told to use iso adapter but still doesn't work!! Is this the adapter kit your talking about?

Comment: Well that has helped thank you if you can tell me how to upload a pic on here i can pop the pics up.

Comment: Well the adapter portion your talking about is exact to the picture you have shown..so the problem must stem from the wiring in the car as they are diff colours?! so i have got pics but doesn't give me option the upload on here!!

Comment: If you edit your post, you can add it by clicking on the small icon at the top center of the text box. It will look like a small rectangle with mountains in it. When you click on it, you'll get a dialog box with two radial selections, leave that part alone, and click on browse. You can then find it in your computer, select it, then click to upload. Make sure the pic is no more than 1kx1k ... don't know the max size, but you can have too big of one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your headlights have to do with an audio system? If you are fitting the audio system yourself, you need to find a switched source of power, one which comes on when you turn the key. The best way to fit this is to buy the adapter kit for it, which will give you a wired adapter which plugs into your car and aligns with the color coding on your radio wiring. This will get you your switched power lead.

Take a look at this image.

[image]

What I'm talking about is the adapter portion which is hanging down. I have no clue what this one is for, but you should have on similar. If you do have one and the end is attached to the car plug, I'd look to see to make sure the wires are aligned correctly. The main power in for your Peugeot should be switched, so the correct adapter will associate this power lead to your head unit.